# somando campo do foreach do controller para a view

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Olá!
Tenho a seguinte função do controlador.

```html
 public function lancamento_listar()
 {
  $lista = $this->lancamento->obter_dados();
  $data = array();
  $no = $_POST['start'];
  foreach ($lista as $lancamento) {
   $no++;
   $row = array();
   $row[] = $lancamento->id;            
   $row[] = $lancamento->tipo == 1 ? '<span class="label label-success">'.'Receita'.'</span>' : '<span class="label label-danger">'.'Despesa'.'</span>';
   $row[] = date('d/m/Y H:i',strtotime($lancamento->dt_lancamento));
   $row[] = $lancamento->descricao;   
   $row[] = date('d/m/Y',strtotime($lancamento->dt_vencimento));   
   $row[] = 'R$ ' .number_format($lancamento->valor, 2, ',', '0');     
   $row[] = $lancamento->recebido == 1 ? '<span class="label label-success">'.'Pago'.'</span>' : '<span class="label label-warnning">'.'Pendente'.'</span>';
   
   //add html para a ação
   $row[] = '<a class="btn btn-flat btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Editar" onclick="editar_lancamento('."'".$lancamento->id."'".')"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
          <a class="btn btn-flat btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Excluir" onclick="excluir_lancamento('."'".$lancamento->id."'".')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>';
  
   $data[] = $row;
  }

  $saida = array(
      "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
      "recordsTotal" => $this->lancamento->lancamento_tudo(),
      "recordsFiltered" => $this->lancamento->lancamento_filtrado(),
      "data" => $data,
    );
  //Saída para o formato json
  echo json_encode($saida);
 }
```

E através do plugin DateTable, estou retornando os dados da base de dados.

Minha questão é que, quero somar os lançamentos e exibi-los em um `<tfoot>`.
Por exemplo:

```html
$totalReceita = 0;

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" style="text-align: right; color: green"> <strong>Total Receitas:</strong></td>
     <td colspan="2" style="text-align: left; color: green"><strong>R$ <?php echo number_format($totalReceita,2,',','.') ?></strong></td>
    </tr>     
</tfoot>
```

Este `$totalReceita` deve ser a soma dos valores em(controller)
`$row[] = 'R$ ' .number_format($lancamento->valor, 2, ',', '0');`

Como fazer este calculo já que os dados estão vindo por ajax ?

Eu consigo fazer esta soma quando o foreach é na própria view, mas não sei fazer isto utilizando o plugin `DataTable` e `Ajax`.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu faria um armazenamento de soma: $total_receita += $lancamento->valor; dentro do loop, ai exibo então no final $total_receita. Eu faria dessa forma.

Comment: E como chamaria no view ?

Answer (score 1):

Como o André comentou:

> Eu faria um armazenamento de soma: 
>   `$total_receita += $lancamento->valor;` dentro do loop, ai exibo então no final $total_receita. Eu faria dessa forma.

Para adicionar à view, você acrescenta essa variável ao array `$saida`:

`$saida = array(
        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
        "recordsTotal" => $this->lancamento->lancamento_tudo(),
        "recordsFiltered" => $this->lancamento->lancamento_filtrado(),
        "data" => $data,
        "soma" => $total_receita,
);`

E na view você imprime a variável normalmente: `$soma`